# How do I add a My Account Item to a New Menu?

Tags: 7, routes

Hi I need to add a My Account link to a new menu. I know about me aliases module and others, but I would like to do it using my own code. Any ideas ?

**Update:** I am using Drupal 6. Is it possible to use the My Account provided by the user module in a differente menu than Navigation ?

Comment: Are you using 6 or 7?  Can you clarify why the "my account" link provided by the core user module isn't adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the "My account" item from the navigation menu.  Visit /admin/build/menu-customize/navigation, and click the edit link for "my account".

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function mymenu_menu() {
$items['user/%user_uid_only_optional'] = array(
'title' => 'My account',
'title callback' => 'user_page_title',
'title arguments' => array(1),
'page callback' => 'user_view_page',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => 'user_view_access',
'access arguments' => array(1),
'menu_name' => 'your-menu',
);
return $items;
}
```

Comment: This should work, but I think it'd be better to define your own to_arg function.  user_uid_only_optional looks like an accident of history, and there could be a conflict if any other module tried to define 'user/%user_uid_only_optional'.

Comment: I tried it but it is still not working. the item simply doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the name of the menu you want to modify, you can do this programmatically.

The best function to start with is `menu_link_save()`. The entire API is explained here:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/group/menu/7

(change the 7 to 6 if you want the D6 version)

You should be able to create a link to the user's page by simply sending the user to `/user`.